# Calculating time from ratios given? (Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, ratio

I was having trouble on cracking this problem algebraically. If I draw pictures and make up numbers it makes sense. But can anyone show me how to do the problem algebraically and show it in such a way as it makes sense. Here's the problem:

> Tom can paint 1 fence in 3 hours. John can paint the same fence in 2 hours. How long would it take them both to paint the same in fence if they worked together?

My first impression was this'd be really easy, and I do consider myself to be good at math. But to be honest I couldn't find a way of doing such a problem in a intuitive and understanding way.

Hopefully you guys have some fun in trying to solve this as well. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work done by Tom in $3$ hours = $1$ fence

Work done by Tom in $1$ hour = $1\over 3$ fence

Similarly, Work done by John in $1$ hour = $1\over 2$ fence

Work done in $1$ hour by the two of them = $1\over 3$ + $1\over 2$ = $5\over 6$

Time taken for $1$ fence = $1\over 5/6$ = $6\over 5$

Comment: LOL are you from IIT? Or one of those math genius. Thanks anyways1

Comment: @Asker123 I am from IIT that's true, but I don't consider myself a math genius after seeing all the experts here on this website. :)

Comment: Nevertheless, thanks!